# Recent sediments from the Central Downwelling Zones of the AMOC

Tags: ocean-currents, atlantic, amoc

I am looking for research trips on recent sediments (from about 1880) from the Central Downwelling Zones of the AMOC. The focus is on the regions: the Irminger Basin and the Labrador Basin.

I especially need shells of foraminifera to determine <sup>18</sup>O.

Do you have an idea of a database that keeps such data or where I can see which expeditions have sampled in the two regions?